# SQL - Adding values to new column in a table from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, distinct-values

I am learning to deal with databases and I came across a task to add new column to existing table and add values to that column using values from another table.

My tables are

```
table_1                          table_2
branch_code| book_id             branch_branch_code| branch_name
        100| 1                                  100| Carnegie
        101| 2                                  102| Reservoir
        102| 3                                  103| JOLIMONT
```

I need to add new column, book_returned_branch to table 1. Add branch name to the new column using branch_code. Branch code is similar to both the tables.

Below is my code and it throws an error: single-row subquery returns more than one row. Please advise!

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 
    SET BOOK_RETURNED_BRANCH = 
    (SELECT BRANCH_NAME FROM TABLE_2 A
    JOIN TABLE_2 B ON A.BRANCH_CODE = B.BRANCH_BRANCH_CODE
    WHERE BRANCH_CODE = (SELECT BRANCH_CODE FROM TABLE_2));
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 
    SET BOOK_RETURNED_BRANCH = (SELECT BRANCH_NAME
                                FROM TABLE_2 t2
                                WHERE table_1.BRANCH_CODE = t2.branch_branch_code
                               );
```

No `JOIN` is needed in the subquery.

Having said that, I strongly discourage you from doing this.  You should simply use `JOIN` when you query the table to get the branch name.

Comment: Can you suggest query with JOIN?

Comment: @PrajwalVenugopal . . . No, I can't.  Oracle doesn't support `JOIN` in `UPDATE` statements (well, except for subqueries).

Answer (score 1):

For add a field to a existing table, you have to use `alter table`. Try the following code:

```
alter table table_1 add BOOK_RETURNED_BRANCH varchar(150);

update
    table_1
set
    BOOK_RETURNED_BRANCH =
    (
        select
            branch_name
        from
            table_2
        where
            table_1.branch_code = table_2.branch_branch_code
    );
```